# Weird behavior on my iOS fetchrequest with two sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, sections

In my tableviewcontroller with **2 sections**, the build works but the App crashes. Crashes at the beginning when I open the detail view controller to add an item to the data store, so that one section will have one item and the other section zero item (because of the two different predicates to generate the sections).

If I set one section only, build the App, store two different Items, one for each section, everything's fine, same number of items for each section. When I set again two sections, re-build the app, run and create a new item, the number for the sections is different: the code will save the item and by turning back to the tableview will crash the app. Why is this?

```
#import "hommedicineTableViewController.h"
#import "cella2.h"

@interface hommedicineTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation hommedicineTableViewController
@synthesize section2Items = _section2Items;
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell3";

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(220/255.f) green:(237/255.f) blue:(231/255.f) alpha:1.0];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([cella2 class]) bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([cella2 class])];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([cella2 class]) bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"archivio like%@", @"in*"];
    NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"archivio like%@", @"ar*"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Medicine"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Medicine"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"archivio" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scadenza" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest1 setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor3 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"archivio" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest2 setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptor3, sortDescriptor2, nil]];
    [fetchRequest1 setPredicate:predicate1];
    [fetchRequest2 setPredicate:predicate2];
    self.contactarray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:nil] mutableCopy];
    _section2Items = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:nil] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
            return [self.contactarray count];
    } else if (section == 1) {
            return [_section2Items count];
    } else {
    return 0;
    }
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cella2 *tcell = (cella2 *)cell;
    NSManagedObject *device1 = [self.contactarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSManagedObject *device2 = [_section2Items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[device1 valueForKey:@"scadenza"]];
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
                                tcell.immagine1.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[device1 valueForKey:@"picture"]];
                                tcell.label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device1 valueForKey:@"nominativo"]];
                                tcell.label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scadenza: %@", dateString];
                                tcell.label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device1 valueForKey:@"archivio"]];
    } else {
                                tcell.label2.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
                                tcell.immagine1.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[device2 valueForKey:@"picture"]];
                                tcell.label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device2 valueForKey:@"nominativo"]];
                                tcell.label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scadenza: %@", dateString];
                                tcell.label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device2 valueForKey:@"archivio"]];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        cella2 *cell = (cella2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [context deleteObject:[self.contactarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }
        [self.contactarray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"seg2" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"seg2"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.contactarray objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        DettaglioViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.contactdb = selectedDevice;
    }
}

 @end
```

Comment: What is the error that is received when the app crashes?

Comment: How do you trigger table reloading after modifying core data?

Comment: Have you tried to add an exception breakpoint to the project (Breakpoint tab/+/Add Exception Breakpoint)?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies in your `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method, specifically these two lines:

```
NSManagedObject *device1 = [self.contactarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSManagedObject *device2 = [_section2Items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If one section has more items than the other, one of these lines will be trying to access an array index out of bounds (ie. indexPath.row will be greater than or equal to the array count).  Just move these lines to fall within the relevant clause of your if/else:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    NSManagedObject *device1 = [self.contactarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[device1 valueForKey:@"scadenza"]];
    tcell.immagine1.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[device1 valueForKey:@"picture"]];
    tcell.label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device1 valueForKey:@"nominativo"]];
    tcell.label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scadenza: %@", dateString];
    tcell.label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device1 valueForKey:@"archivio"]];
} else {
    NSManagedObject *device2 = [_section2Items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[device2 valueForKey:@"scadenza"]];
    tcell.label2.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    tcell.immagine1.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[device2 valueForKey:@"picture"]];
    tcell.label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device2 valueForKey:@"nominativo"]];
    tcell.label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scadenza: %@", dateString];
    tcell.label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device2 valueForKey:@"archivio"]];
}
```

There are tidier ways of coding it, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks pbasdf, It runs!!